# Autopep8 format "max-line-length" parameter is not working for the imports section

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autopep8

I'm using autopep8 auto-formatter in VSCode (MacOs) but I can't seem to make it work to split lines greater than `max-line-length` in the imports section. In the rest of the code file, it works well, but not in the imports section.
These are my configurations in settings.json:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
"--max-line-length",
"80",
],
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": false,
"python.linting.enabled": true,
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That way of adding autopep8 args is deprecated. It shows up greyed out in your `settings.json`. Instead add this:

```json
"autopep8.args": [
    "--max-line-length=120"
],
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to specify the length as value, not parameter, like so:

```
 "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
        "--max-line-length=80"
        ],
```